# How do I make Process start automatically when Message box is loaded?

Tags: c#, forms

So I made a custom "MessageBox" so that while the file is downloading, a  MessageBox Pops up with a loading gif.

But the thing is it doesn't continue to the rest of the code, it just stops until the person exits out of that MessageBox, then it continues the proccess.

I'm still fairly new to coding so I don't know the exact script to write.

```
        var output = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} Will Now Start Downloading.", "Something",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        MsggBox = new Form3();
        MsggBox.ShowDialog();

      //Right Here I want the Custom MessageBox(Form3) to Pop up and continue with the script. But it just stops the whole script.

        using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {

            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) =>
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"{fileName} Download Complete!", "Something",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                Process.Start(output);
                _Busy = false;
            };

            client.DownloadProgressChanged += (sender, args) => progressBar1.Value = args.ProgressPercentage;
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), output);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Execution stops at `ShowDialog()`, as you've observed.  You need to move the download code  into `Form3` itself, and start the download from there...

Comment: Why do you mean by move the code in to "Form3 itself"?

Comment: try using `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`

Comment: In the `Shown()` event of your `Form3`, start a **BackgroundWorker** or a **Task**.

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox.ShowDialog
```

is blocking process. 
You can try:

1. Run MsgBox.ShowDialog in other thread.

   new Thread( ()=> new Form3().ShowDialog());
2. Run the webClient first in async then show the messagebox.

Comment: This'll cause headaches if you try to communicate between Form3 and your other Forms...

Comment: Well, yes, it will cause headache if we don't keep the Form referenced. But, I guess what he need is to display gif image. So, I think we didn't need communication in this case.

Comment: We can add event in the form to tell that the progress has been done that it close itself as well in that case. But for sure, my answer is not intended to have 2 ways of communication. But it can start with that. :)